# Oracle index creation strategies

Tags: performance, oracle, indexing

Can any body help to to solve following performance issue.

```
select 1
from table_1 a
     ,table_2 b
     ,table_3 c
where c.trx_date between sysdate-12 and sysdate-12
and  c.trx_id=b.trx_id
and  c.type_id=a.type_id;
```

Here I need to create index on table_3 on column trx_date  because this is main filter to sql query.

Now my question is does index requires other column which is used on join query with other table.

for above query does i need to create index with column trx_date ,trx_id,type_id

or index on only trx_date  will solve performance issue?

Regards,
Vijay Nalawade

Comment: Don't guess, look at your execution plans.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely have to create indexes on the columns you use for foreign keys, it helps you to avoid deadlocks.

I have nothing to say about `trx_date` because I don't know about your table structure and table contents. It make sense to create indexes if you want to extract 0-20% of your rows (the exact percent number depends on the record volume) in other cases oracle will perform full scan. The optimizer will evaluate how many blocks it needs to read from the filesystem into the cache and choose the way with the least number, If during full scan it reads fewer blocks oracle will do full scan

Comment: Hello

The condition on column trx_date extract 02-05 percent of row from table so we need to create the index.

table_1 and table are just master table and contain few records and table_3 is transaction table which contain hudge data.

Comment: If so definitely create indexes at least to find out if it gives you some speed.